# How to improve Graphics in Virtual Machine VirtualBox?

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander 32Bit with Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2.
I have a Virtual machine with XP using VirtualBox with the following settings:
[image: VirtualBoxSettings]

I've tried setting the memory value with a bigger value, but whenever I get the browser it will show something like the following:
[image]

It is the same using IE.

### Edits:

- **First Edit:** It used to work normally a couple of months ago (can't remember if it worked after upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04).

Comment: Installed guest additions?

Comment: @Web-E Yes sir.

Comment: This appears to be a bug with accelerated graphics. Try to disable 3D-acceleration from VBox settings (Reference: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=314491). See also the solution running Chrome with the `--disable-accelerated-compositing` flag. As this is a bug it is considered to be off topic here.

Comment: @Takkat That worked indeed. However I bet this is not off topic. Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/tags/virtualization/info), considering that the problem occurs just on virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by disabling the **GPU Accelerated Canvas 2D** flag in chrome:

- Access chrome and type *about:flags* in the address box, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Look for **GPU Accelerated Canvas 2D** and hit on <kbd>Disable</kbd>.